# Any way to pass a checkbox value in Freeform (not Pro version)?

Tags: solspace-freeform

I have a contact form that has a checkbox so the user can choose to also be added to the newsletter subscription with their contact form submission.  Basically this just needs to post a value of "y" and the client manually adds them to their mailing list.

The free version of Freeform no longer has a checkbox fieldtype (Freeform 3.x did). Freeform Pro is an awesome addon, but the only added feature I need is the checkbox field type.

Has anyone figured out a way to pass the value of a checkbox field with the free version?

I tried the Freeform Values extension: https://github.com/stovepot/freeform_values.ee_addon but I wasn't able to get it to work at all - and there is no support for it (bummer).  Basically the tag I used `{freeform:value:optin_check}` shows up in the html output instead of a value.

I thought maybe I could take the value of the checkbox and pass it to a hidden text field, something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="optin_check" name="optin_check" value="Yes">
<input type="hidden" id="optin" name="optin" value="">
```

What I tried with the above extension:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="optin_check" name="optin_check" value="Yes">
<input type="hidden" id="optin" name="optin" value="{freeform:value:optin_check}">
```

Any ideas on how I could get something like this to work?

**Complete Freeform code in my template:**

```
{exp:freeform:form
    collection="Contact"
    return="/contact/thanks"
    inline_errors="yes"
    require_captcha="yes" 
    inline_error_return="contact/error"
    admin_notify="jessica@toolstudios.com"
    template="contact_us"
    form:id="contact-us"    
}

    <p>
        <label for="first_name" class="left">First Name<br>
            <input type="text" value="" name="first_name" id="first_name">
        </label>
        
        <label for="last_name">Last Name<br>
            <input type="text" value="" name="last_name" id="last_name">
        </label>
    </p>
            
    <p>
        <label for="email" class="left">Email<br>
            <input type="email" value="" name="email" id="email">
        </label>
        
        <label for="confirm_email">Confirm Email<br>
            <input type="email" value="" name="confirm_email" id="confirm_email">
        </label>    
    </p>
            
    <p>
        <label for="user_message">Message<br>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="20" id="user_message" name="user_message">
            </textarea>
        </label>
    </p>
    
    <p class="checkbox left">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="optin_check[]" value="Yes">
        <label for="optin_check" class="checker">
            Yes, sign me up to recieve the newsletter!
        </label>
        <input type="hidden" id="optin" name="optin" class="optin" value="">
    </p>
    {if captcha}
    <p class="captcha">
        <label class="long">
        Please answer the security question<span class="required">*</span><br>
        {captcha} &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" name="captcha" id="captcha">
        </label>
    </p>
    {/if}                           
    <p class="left">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
        
{/exp:freeform:form}
```

**And here's a screenshot for the visual:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about trying this on it's own (without a hidden input field) using the freeform_values addon:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="optin" value="Y" {if '{freeform:value:optin}' == 'Y'}checked{/if}>
```

Just be sure that the name of your checkbox field is in fact "*optin*".

Does that work?

Comment: Aha! Yes that way worked :) I had tried the conditional before but I must have had my syntax wrong or something... because nothing was working, and that's when I started to try using a hidden field. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: No probs. You were close but it just needed some tweaking. :)

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem, but I couldn't get the above to work. What am I missing? @ian @ByteMyPixel

`<div><label for="optin1">
         <span>Get information *</span>
         <input type="checkbox" id="optin1" name="optin" value="Y" {if '{freeform:value:optin}' == 'Y'}checked{/if}>
        </label>
        <label for="optin2">
         <span>Conduct research * [Ethical approval received Y/N]</span>
         <input type="checkbox" id="optin2" name="optin" value="Y" {if '{freeform:value:optin}' == 'Y'}checked{/if}>
        </label>
        
</div>`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="optin_check" name="optin_check" value="Yes">
```

to :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="optin_check" name="optin_check[]" value="Yes">
```

Comment: thanks for helping! Unfortunately that produces the same result...  I'm still getting the Freeform Value tag in the output.

Comment: Can you be more clear with what you are trying to do? Perhaps post code for your complete template...

Comment: For sure, basically it's just a contact form with a checkbox option to be added to the newsletter subscription.  I'll update my question with the full template and a screenshot.

Comment: What is the name of the freeform checkbox field? You have name="optin_check[]" and name="optin" in your code. Do you need both? Make sure you are adding the [] to the correctly named input field.

Comment: That's the problem, the free version of Freeform doesn't have a checkbox field, and I didn't really want to purchase the pro version just for a checkbox field.  The hidden field, name="optin" is the other field I added to try to pass the checkbox value to and capture in freeform.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work with {freeform:field:my_newsletter} as my_newsletter is the name of the newsletter.