# Question regarding Freeform Pro Fields

Tags: solspace-freeform

I want to make a new field "untick box if you do not want to receive the e-newsletter' I am using Freeform Pro

Is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you just use a checkbox??

http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/default_fieldtypes/#checkbox

Of course you'll want to work your caption carefully (untick to  ...) and you probably want to render the checkbox yourself instead of letting freeform do it, so you can set it to checked to start with

```
<input type="checkbox" id="freeform_field_id" name="freeform_field_id" value="Y" {if '{freeform:value:optin}' == 'Y'}checked=checked{/if} />
```

Also, see here : [FreeForm PRO checkbox requied field](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14498/freeform-pro-checkbox-requied-field) its not got an answer ticked but is relivent.

And here : [Any way to pass a checkbox value in Freeform (not Pro version)?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9238/any-way-to-pass-a-checkbox-value-in-freeform-not-pro-version)

Comment: No problem, if it helps you solve then please mark a the answer so others can find the solutions.